# Android Device Monitor, An error has occured

Tags: android

I know this question has already been answered but still I am unable to launch Android Device Monitor on my system.

Steps I have tried

- Run Android Studio as Administrator
- launched Android Device Monitor from the command line as well as from Android     Studio -> View > Tool Windows > Terminal
- C:\Users\Ankur Sharma\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\lib\monitor-x86_64\monitor.exe
- C:\Users\Ankur Sharma\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools\monitor.bat

In some of the cases I got the error "Android Device Monitor is already launched"

- Start Task Manager and close all monitor.exe.

I am using 64-bit java

[image: JAVA_HOME system environment variable]

[Log File](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IWLNj.png)

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I decided to uninstall the android studio and installed it by right-clicking >> Run as administrator. Now I can see my android device monitor window, also all my projects are still there.
[Android Device Monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VldEH.png)